# Graph of a sequence of a function

Tags: graphing-functions, sequence-of-function

I have encountered a question that sketch the $x^n$ sequence on $[0,1]$ but I’m not sure how can I draw it with my hand. Isn’t it 3-dimensional?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a different color for each $n$, or use a solid line, then a dashed line, then a dotted line, and so on.

Comment: I'm guess they mean for you to draw the curves $y=x^n$ for a few representative values of $n$ on the same set of axes.